# Error handler telegram bot

Tags: php, laravel, telegram-bot

I create telegram bot with laravel and [sdk](https://telegram-bot-sdk.readme.io/docs/) Today there is a problem - the bot is recursively sending the same message to the user like this [picture](http://joxi.ru/Y2LELvKsndPNRA)

```
\Telegram::sendMessage([
                'chat_id' => $chatid,
                'text' => "Считаю...",
            ]);

            $controller = $this->getReportControllerName($text);
            $method = $this->getReportMethodName($text);
            $report_data = new $controller();
            $report_data = $report_data->$method($chatid);

            try
            {
                \Telegram::sendMessage([
                    'chat_id' => $chatid,
                    'text' => $report_data,
                ]);
            }
            catch (TelegramResponseException $e)
            {
                $errorData = $e->getResponseData();

                if ($errorData['ok'] === false) {
                    \Telegram::sendMessage([
                        'chat_id' => '123456789',
                        'text'    => 'There was an error for a user. ' . $errorData['error_code'] . ' ' . $errorData['description'],
                    ]);
                }
            }
```

`Try-catch block` add after detection problem. In my logs there are lots of `499` and `500` errors. What else can I do to resolve this problem? Add `try-catch` to another part of program or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to respond 200 OK on webhook, else telegram tries send message again and again and again.

You need to catch all exceptions and respond 200 OK on every request.

In your's part of code you may use:

```
try
        {
            return \Telegram::sendMessage([
                'chat_id' => $chatid,
                'text' => $report_data,
            ]);
        }
```

Comment: you mean, that its correct try-catch which I added(in question)?

Comment: @sandy,  you can do that, but more important just return 200 OK response. You can add `return response()
            ->json(['success'=> true])` or something else like this at the and of controller's method